# C++ CPU not full utilized

Tags: c++, performance, csv, eigen

I met a strange performance reduction in C++, can someone help me to identify what's the problem?

I am doing a out-of-sample forecasting problem based on Eigen Library. I use a expanding window method to incorporate a new vector of observation and use LBFGS method to maximize the likelihood function.

Specifically, in the for loop, I choose a subset block `Y` of my data `mY` (`Y = mY.block(0,0,24,756+i)`), and use this subset of data to estimate the parameter by `callLBFGS` function and store the estimates in vP vector (I pass `vP` by reference). Next, I copy the value of `vP` into a result matrix `mRet`, and finlly I write the `mRet` to a csv file.

The reason I put the WriteCSV in the loop is that `callLBFGS` is very time-consuming. If the optimization fails, I want to abort the program and debugging, but I don't want to lose my estimates that are already optimized, so I write it to csv every time that it finishes a loop. I don't see the problem of putting the `WriteCSV` inside the loop at all, since `callLBFGS` usually takes up to 10 minutes, but write a 102 x 40 matrix into csv usually takes milliseconds.

Here is my problem: **the `callLBFGS` function I write is multi-threaded using OpenMP, without putting the `WriteCSV` function inside the loop, the CPU utilization is 95%-100%, but with `WriteCSV` function inside the loop, the CPU utilization drops to 50%-60%.**

This is very strange and beyond my knowledge, considering that `callLBFGS` consumes thousands times more of time than `WriteCSV`. CPU shouldn't spend much time in scheduling and forking new thread. Can someone help me to identify the problem? Many many thanks !

```
MatrixXd mY = mData.transpose();

double adFunc;
char *Result = "BFGSEst.csv";

VectorXd vP(102);
MatrixXd Y;
Matrix<double,102,40> mRet;
vP = IniPar.col(0);

for (int i = 0; i < 40; ++i) {

    Y = mY.block(0,0,24,756+i);
    callLBFGS(vP,&adFunc,Y,10000);
    mRet.col(i) = vP;
    WriteCSV(Result,mRet);  /*this is the killer*/
}
```

My function callLBFGS and WriteCSV is looks like this:

```
void callLBFGS(VectorXd &vP, double *adFunc, MatrixXd &Y, int MaxIter);
void WriteCSV(char *filename, MatrixXd X);
```

**EDIT***
Many thanks for all your replies. Below is my implementation of `WriteCSV`, quite naive. To clarify, I said `callLBFGS` takes up to 10 mins is that **each call** of `callLBFGS` takes up to 10 mins (multi-dimensional minimization). So the entire loop takes hours to finish. I know if `callLBFGS` and `WriteCSV` consume similar time, it is not surprise that the CPU would not be full utilized. But here is that `WriteCSV` takes far less time than `callLBFGS`, I should not expect that the CPU usage decrease to that large extent during the process of `callLBFGS`.

```
void WriteCSV(char *filename, MatrixXd X){
  ofstream myfile;
  myfile.open (filename);

  for (int i = 0; i < X.rows(); ++i)
  {
      for (int j = 0; j < X.cols(); ++j)
      {
          myfile<<X(i,j);
          if (j!=X.cols()-1)
          {
             myfile<<",";
          }else{
             myfile<<"\n";
          }
      } 
  }
  myfile.close();
}
```

Comment: Probably because `WriteCSV` is doing I/O operations that don't consume 100% of CPU.

Comment: Isn't it obvious? `callLBFGS` is a computation task. `WriteCSV` is an IO task. Your program stops being CPU bound, and gets limited by IO. HDDs aren't infinitely fast. In other words, CPu has to wait for IO to finish, so gets some spare time.

Comment: Can you share your implementation of `WriteCSV`?

Comment: Probably not relevant for the problem in hand, but you should pass MatrixXd as a reference or preferably as a const reference to WriteCSV as it now makes an unnecessary copy.

Comment: As I understand it, there's concurrency only in `callLBFGS` while the rest of the program runs single-threaded, including the file IO.

Comment: Is `vP` cleared at any point?

Comment: I think you should use a profiler.

Comment: Do you see the CPU usage drop even in the first call (first 10 minutes) when you introduce code that happens much later?

Comment: @HannoBinder, yes you are right, I only parallel `callLBFGS` using 12 threads (I have 6 physical cores). I do not clear `vP` at any point, I only copy the optimized `vP` into `mRet.col(i)`, then I write the `mRet` to csv. I just learned C++ for 1 month, is there any problem that I do not clear `vP`? Should I? Thank you!

Comment: @mtk99, wow you are so sharp! The CPU usage does not drop in the first  `callLBFGS` call (the first 10 mins). But it drops from the second call...This is also a point I don't understand...

Comment: @HannoBinder, by the way, I think I can't clear `vP` at any point of time. Since I need use the previous optimized `vP` as starting values for the next `callLBFGS` optimization, that's why I pass `vP` by reference.

Comment: Sorry, I overlooked that `vP` is already limited in size, so there really is no danger of it growing from iteration to iteration. Just ignore `vP` for now :)

Comment: Just for fun, try putting your CSV on a RAMdisk, or writing it straight to `stdout` and directing it to `/dev/null`

Comment: By now, I don't think that your problem is strictly IO related. Can you verify that in each iteration `callLBFGS` is executed with the same number of threads? Maybe something is causing OpenMP to use less concurrency from the second iteration on. "50-60% CPU" sounds like only half of the cores are used, i.e. only half as many threads are running as should be.

Comment: I guess your matrix classes uses implicit sharing, so they may make deep or shallow copies depending on the usage. My guess is that adding a function triggers a different way of making the copy and cause a false sharing. Make sure your allocations are aligned to cache line boundaries.

Answer (score 2):

Sorry this should be just a comment, but I can't yet

There might be a lazy evaluation happening invisibly within MatrixXd<>.

The lazy evaluation possibly happens within WriteCSV(...) and this coupled with necessarily single threaded IO drops your total CPU utilization.

The deferred or lazy evaluation could be anywhere but is probably hidden in a simple retrieval or copy statement like:

```
mRet.col(i) = vP;
```

or

```
myfile<<X(i,j);
```

Other posters are all likely more correct and I endorse the suggestion to thread out the IO.

Answer (score 1):

For I/O operations, you don't have much in your hands and so you cannot do much about it. So, add your optimization to cpu bound processes or the cpu bound part of your process! because that is in your hands up to a great extent. This writeCSV function is an I/O bound process which is executing 40 times in contrast to it's execution by one time when you did not include it in your loop.

Comment: "since they are user bounded"?!

Comment: I don't consider writing to a file to be user interaction.

Comment: @Anonymous70: edit your answer to say "I/O bound", and then it might get some up-votes.

Comment: You're still confusing I/O bound with interactive.  "interactive" usually means "user-interaction", not "interacting with I/O devices".

Answer (score 1):

Considering that you passed `MatrixXd` by value, the quickest fix would be to spin up a separate thread to do the actual writing, detach and return immediately.

And as a minor improvement, I'd write `','` instead of `","` but that's more a style thing.

Answer (score 1):

I see two issues in your code:

1. You are using C++ streams that are not known for their high performance :)
2. You are waiting for the file I/O to complete before starting the next iteration.

To address the first issue, I would use a good old `printf()`. For the second - asynchronous I/O; make a copy of the passed-in matrix (you already pass a copy of it), start the I/O and return.